# Book where robots are in control of the Earth, send humans to another planet where they have to behave like robots themselves

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book where robots are in control of the Earth. They send humans to another planet where the humans have to behave like robots themselves, or they would be killed by the other robots. At the end, it is revealed that everyone on the planet is human.

Comment: [Star Diaries - The Eleventh Voyage](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JtdyCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT47&lpg=PT47&dq=kempootar+gun&source=bl&ots=weiEsoq7wR&sig=VgNn0TRKbQzk2gXOPV5_cSiebA4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRldTCqpPTAhUBvBoKHWruDtkQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=kempootar%20gun&f=false)?

Comment: Probably not Tucker's *Wares* tetratology although some of the themes match up like murderous robots and humans trying to blend in.

Comment: @Valorum That's what I thought too, but that doesn't really match the first part of the title.

Comment: @Sarah your question has very few details.  Please look at http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info for how to improve story-id questions.

Comment: Sorry that I cannot give more detailed information. It was just a book recommendation by a collegue who forgot the title (and author) ;) nevertheless it sounded pretty fascinating, so I just tried it here. Actually, it could be star diaries, I have to ask my collegue next time I see him